# How to access a excel file (stored on a harddisk) from internet

Tags: python, html, excel, web-services, raspberry-pi

I am designing a nurse call system. i am using python script for raspberry pi to manage display. when any call is made by the patient it will be shown on display and a excel file on raspberry pi will store the call information like bed no, time etc. Now I want to access the excel file from internet. How could I do that? kindly suggest  me the procedure. any kind of help will be highly obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Rewrite my Comment as Answer:

> I would suggest you do either write a normal Desktop app or to use a
>   MySql Database. If you make such Question youre are not going to get
>   an Answer without showing your own efford to solve the Problem. This
>   Cummunity is about solving Problems, not about writing Code for guys
>   who are to lazy to Google

I just googled Python Excel and this was the first entry: http://www.python-excel.org/

Is that enough Answer?

Comment: My program is able to create a excel file and save  real time data in it. i want to access the excel file from anywhere using web browser . i am new to this function. if you could help how to do it i will be obliged. and for your information i am not a lazy person. thank you.

Comment: The site I linked above serves a Package what gives you the abiatillity to read from an Execl File. There are also some Tutorials about HowTo